# How to add textfield in header sections?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to add material-ui textfield on Header section. In desktop view I have showed textfiled on image and in mobile view I have removed image. My code working fine in desktop view but in mobile view on click of textfield screen goes shrink.

Below is my code with screen shots

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Paper,
  makeStyles,
  Typography,
  InputAdornment,
  Grid,
  Box,
 // TextField,
  Hidden,
  FormControl,
  OutlinedInput,
} from '@material-ui/core';
//import HeaderText from '../Common/HeaderText';
import { GlobalStyle } from '../../styles/GlobalStyle';
import TypedReact from '../Common/TypedReact';
import { Event } from '../../Tracking/Event';
import ImagePro from '../Image/ImagePro';
import landingblur from '../../images/landingpageblur.jpg';
//import DraftsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Drafts';
import ContactUs from '../Common/ContactUs';
const useStyles = makeStyles(GlobalStyle);
export default function Header() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [email, setState] = React.useState('');

   const handleChange = (e: any) => {
     setState(e.target.value);
   };

  const [src, { blur }]: any = ImagePro(
    landingblur,
    'https://abc.xyz.net/smallsizeimages/x.png',
    //landing,
  );

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Paper
        square
        elevation={0}
        className={classes.g_landingcontainer}
        style={{ position: 'relative', background: '#ffcc00' }}
      >
        <img
          src={src}
          style={{
            filter: blur ? 'blur(20px)' : 'none',
            transition: blur ? 'none' : 'filter 0.3s ease-out',
          }}
          className={classes.g_headerimage}
        />
        <Box className={classes.g_landingotherheader}>
          <Grid container>
            <Hidden smDown>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Typography variant="h1" align="left">
                  hello there xyz <br />
                  <TypedReact
                    typeSpeed={70}
                    backSpeed={30}
                    loop={true}
                    strings={[
                      'movies',
                      'IT',
                      'Tax',
                      'MCA',
                      'BCA',
                       ]}
                  />{' '}
                  <br />
                </Typography>
              </Grid>
            </Hidden>
            <Hidden smUp>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Typography variant="h1">
                  hello xyz{' '}
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="h2">
                  <TypedReact
                    typeSpeed={70}
                    backSpeed={30}
                    loop={true}
                    strings={[
                      'movies',
                      'IT',
                      'Tax',
                      'MCA',
                      'BCA',
                      
                    ]}
                  />{' '}
                  <br />
                </Typography>
              </Grid>
            </Hidden>
            <Grid item xs={10} md={6}>
              <Typography
                variant="body1"
                style={{ color: '#3f3c3d' }}
                className={classes.g_landbanner}
              >
                  skjdamlsdmla alsdjlaksla asldjakllas
              </Typography>
            </Grid>
            <br />
            <br />
            <Grid container>
              <Grid item xs={11} md={3}>
                <br />
                 <FormControl fullWidth variant="outlined">
              <OutlinedInput
              name="Email"
              autoComplete="off"
              value={email}
              fullWidth
              onChange={handleChange}
             
                endAdornment={
                  <InputAdornment position="end">
                     <ContactUs
                            variant="contained"
                            text={email}
                          />
                  </InputAdornment>
                }
                placeholder="Enter your email"
              />
            </FormControl>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Box>
      </Paper>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

CSS part code

```
 g_landingcontainer: {
      height: '100vh',
      
      [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
        //height: '80vh',
        //height: '90vh',
        minHeight:'90vh'
      },
    },
 g_headerimage: {
      maxWidth: '100%',
      display: 'flex',
      width: '100vw',
      // height: '900px',

      [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
        display: 'none',
      },
    },
 g_landingotherheader: {
      letterSpacing: '0.01em',
      textAlign: 'left',
      position: 'absolute',
      marginLeft: '2em',

      [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
        top: '12%',
      },
      [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
        //top: '14%',
        top: '10%',
      },
      [theme.breakpoints.up('lg')]: {
        top: '10%',
      },
    },
 g_landbanner: {
      [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
        marginTop: '20%',
      },
      [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
        marginTop: '5%',
        marginBottom: '5%',
        //        marginBottom: '2%',
      },
    },
```

mobile view screen shot
[image: mobile view]

[image: mobile view after click of textfiled]